# PHP: Form Mark tag not displaying with errors

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

Created a mail form for a contact section. There's a mark tag after the form that displays after validating that all required fields aren't satisfied and lists which ones need to be satisfied.

Upon submitting though, if values are entered, they are echoed as they're suppose to, HOWEVER the mark tag does not display...

I need help with having the mark tag display when there are errors...

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="invoice" placeholder="Invoice Number (optional)" value="<?php echo $_POST['invoice']; ?>">
    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="10" placeholder="Please enter your comments here..." value="<?php echo $_POST['comments'];?>"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>             
<mark><?php echo $MSG[0]; ?></mark>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST)) {
$POST=filter_post($_POST);
$MSG=check_empty($POST);
if(!array_filter($MSG)) {
    send_mail($POST);
    if(send_mail($POST)) {
        $MSG[]="Email Success";
    }
    else {
        $MSG[]="Email Failed";
    }
}
}

function filter_post($POST) {
$keys=array('name', 'phone', 'email', 'invoice', 'comments');
$POST=array_intersect_key($POST, array_flip($keys));
$POST=array_map('strip_tags', $POST);
return($POST);
}

function check_empty($POST) {
foreach($POST as $key=> $value) {
    if(empty($value)) {
        $MSG[]="You need to fill out the $key section";
    }
}
return($MSG);
}

function send_mail($POST) {
extract($POST);
$to='7servicerepairs@gmail.com';
$sbj='New Question For Se7en Service!';
$msg="Name: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Invoice #: $invoice \n Comments: $comments";
$headers="From: $email";
return(mail($to, $sbj, $msg, $headers));
}

?>
```

CSS:

```
form{
cursor: default !important;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-self: center;
align-self: center;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
background: #ECF0F1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
-webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
border-radius: 0.3em;
padding: 1.3em;
}
form>input{
width: 22.1em;
height: 2.5em;
margin: 0.2em 0;
font-size: 1em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #7C7C7C;
outline: none;
}
form>button{
width: 22.35em;
height: 2.5em;
margin: 0.2em 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 1em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
border: none;
color: #fff;
background: #2ECC71;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
form>textarea{
margin: 0.2em 0;
font-size: 1em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #7C7C7C;
outline: none;
max-width: 22em;
}
mark{
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-self: center;
align-self: center;
height: 1.5em;
margin: 1.5em;
font-size: 1em;
color: #fff;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White letters over no background? It is surely there, you just can't distinguish it.

```
mark {
...
color: #ff0000;
...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hsh4zmb/

Comment: You're right. I feel so stupid. However, even though I changed the mark color, it still didn't show up red, until I changed my <mark> tag to a <p> tag... Either way it works now. Thanks

Comment: ignore the <mark> issue. program was malfunctioning... all is good